# Server Error after upgrade to 5.46.3 or higher

Tags: upgrade, drupal-7

When upgrading from CiviCRM 5.35.2 to 5.46.3, I get a server error. I use CiviCRM in Drupal 7. To update, I drag the file with `wget https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.46.3-drupal.tar.gz`, transfer it to the directory and then update the database, as usual. After the update, there are some pages and calls that cause a server error, for example `/civicrm/a/#/status`. It crashes the entire PHP process. We have followed this and I set the log here. In the log it is obvious that the file is not found. I compared the path with other installations and found that the files and paths are available in CiviCRM with Drupal9!

```
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal/src/CRM/Core/DomainTokens.php", 0x7ffc989647e0) = -1 ENOENT (file or directory not found)
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal/src/CRM/Core", 0x7ffc989645e0) = -1 ENOENT (file or directory not found)
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal/src/CRM", 0x7ffc989643f0) = -1 ENOENT (file or directory not found)
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal/src", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer/../pear", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/composer", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all/modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites/all", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]/sites", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("[path]", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

Why is a path normally used in Drupal9 called in the Drupal7 installation?

Comment: `vendor/composer/../pear/pear-core-minimal/src/CRM/Core/DomainTokens.php` doesn't make any sense in drupal 9 either. There shouldn't be CRM/Core/DomainTokens.php under the pear-core-minimal package.

Comment: Thank you, Demerit. I created a symlink from `/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/CRM/Core/DomainTokens.php` to `CRM/Core/DomainTokens.php`.  Now the php process does not crash! But it ends in an huge call stack site with "deprecated curly braces", not really helpful. It's still mystery why `/civicrm/a/#/status` calls the wrong path after an update.

Comment: It seems that https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.reltoken/issues/20 causes the error. With disabling and uninstalling the extension, `/civicrm/a/#/status` works. I check other funktions later.